# Dropzone plugin add input for each uploaded image

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropzone.js

Has anyone tried to add an input text to each image? I want to have the ability for the user to name each image.

I have looked around but no one has done it. Is it actually possible to modify the preview template?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to change the template. Maybe you can add an input text and change the image name when the input lose focus.

[Here explain how](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-previewTemplate)